# Hi guys, how can I get all the meta ID that has the key-value “aacain”: “Anthony Acain”

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Here is the sample doc. I tried unnesting. Also tried searching objects inside and array for couchbase.

```
{
  "bluetooth": false,
  "doctype": "mobileconfig",
  "sections": [
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "alias": "Assigned To",
          "dropDownOptions": {
            "aacain": "Anthony Acain",
          },
        }
      ],
      "sectiontitle": "Service Order Information"
    },

  ],
}
```

I tried

```
SELECT meta(g).id from geo as g
unnest ???
where ???
```

Comment: You said what have you tried, but you didn't show it. Please post your code, so others can help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by meta id. meta().id should give you the document ID, but you're asking for the meta ID of "aacain". Are you looking to return "aacain" in a query? Are you looking to return the name of every child of dropDownOptions? The first one? The one that has a given value? We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following index and query

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default ( DISTINCT ARRAY (DISTINCT ARRAY f.dropDownOptions.aacain FOR f IN s.fields END) FOR s IN sections END ) WHERE doctype = "mobileconfig";

SELECT RAW META(d).id
FROM default AS d
WHERE d.doctype = "mobileconfig"
AND ANY s IN d.sections SATISFIES (ANY f IN s.fields SATISFIES f.dropDownOptions.aacain = "Anothony  Acain" END) END;
```